# Android SQLiteDatabase.delete method wouldn't delete using where args

Tags: android

Watch how i call the `db.delete` method; if I do the following a record is successfully deleted:

```
public void deteleProfile(Long id) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Integer i = db.delete(ProlificDatabase.TABLE, "_id=?", new String[] {id.toString()});
        Log.d(TAG, i + " records deleted where id is " + id);
```

however if I do this:

```
public void deteleProfile(Long id) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Integer i = db.delete(ProlificDatabase.TABLE, "?=?", new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,id.toString()});
        Log.d(TAG, i + " records deleted where id is " + id);
```

no records are deleted. also no exceptions or warnings are raised to say something has gone wrong.

in case you didn't catch it, the difference between the two calls were:

`..."_id=?", new String[] {id.toString()});`

vs

`..."?=?", new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,id.toString()});`

documentation for BaseColumns._ID is:

`public static final String _ID` with a `Constant Value: "_id"`

The latter way seems to make for neater code, but why doesn't it work?

**EDIT:**
I suspect the `whereargs` parameter only applies to the right side of an expression.

Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Strings you provide in `whereArgs` are escaped and enclosed in '

```
"?=?", new String[] {BaseColumns._ID,id.toString()});
```

translates to

```
'_id'='1234'
```

which is valid SQLite syntax but does string comparison instead of a table lookup. Since "_id" is not the same String as "1234" (or any other number) the expression will always evaluate to false and nothing will get deleted.

What you should use is the following syntax

```
Integer i = db.delete(ProlificDatabase.TABLE, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[] {id.toString()});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void deteleProfile(Long id) throws SQLException 
  {
     SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
     Integer i = db.delete(ProlificDatabase.TABLE, "_id=" + id, null);
     Log.d(TAG, i + " records deleted where id is " + id);
  }
```

and [this link](http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/#title) is a good example of SQLite database of android.

Comment: my question is why using where args parameter does not work.I already know how a delete a row ;-)

Comment: Have you added a column _id in your table ?